# framework 7 routes - events handlers not working

Tags: html-framework-7

My simple goal is to load a main index.html and on top of it to show a login page, if user is not already logged. For this reason I defined the following route in my app router.

```
let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        url: './index.html',
        on: {
            pageInit: function (e, page) {
                if (localStorage.loggedIn != 1 || localStorage.loggedIn == 'undefined') {
                    this.navigate({ name: 'login' });
                }
            }
        }
    },
    ....
```

Overall, this works, but with a few drawbacks.

- If user navigates directly to the main site , pageInit is received
  adn everything is fine. But if the user navigates to
  main_site.com/index.html the pageInit is not triggered (which
  obviously is normal) and login form does not pop.
- I don't receive the rest of the events, like pageMounted,
  pageAfterIn, etc. I can't understand why is that.

Anyone with ideas what's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0):

if i am right, F7 looks for the route not necessarily the index file soo according to your script it shows only a route with a path

```
path: '/'
```

and not one with a path

```
path: '/index.html'
```

so thats why when you call main_site it works because the path is `'/'`, and the other is obvious because of the missing `'/index.html'` path

My suggestion is you stick to opening through routed paths, pages dont load directly